# Help with jQuery Delegate

Tags: jquery, ajax

Im trying to use .delegate to assign click events to dynamically loaded content. As you scroll additional content is loaded via Ajax.

Here is the jQuery I have written which works for the static content but not for the content that gets loaded dynamically:

```
$('#fav').delegate("#submit", "click", function() {

    var favid = $("input#favid").val();
    var favsave = 'favid=' + favid;
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "fav.php",
      data: favsave,
      success: function() {
        $('#fav').fadeOut(100);
      }
    });
    return false;

});
```

Here is my HTML:

Button

http://a2.twimg.com/profile_images/499579722/Lambda_twitterPic_normal.gif'alt='lambdasolutions' title='lambdasolutions' />
      http://twitter.com/lambdasolutions' alt='lambdasolutions' title='lambdasolutions'>lambdasolutions

```
  <div class='atweet'>Why Use Moodle? | 
    <a target='_blank' href="http://bit.ly/aLld9q">http://bit.ly/aLld9q</a> | <a target="_blank" href="http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23moodle">#moodle</a> 
    <a target="_blank" href="http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23elearning">#elearning</a> 
    <a target="_blank" href="http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23edtech">#edtech</a> 
  </div>

  <div class='date'>16-09-2010 22:44</div>

    <form id='fav' method='post' class='options' action=''>
      <input style='display: none;' type='text' name='fav' id='favid' value='24699868222' />
      <input type='submit' value='Add to Favorites' name='submit' id='submit' />
    </form>
</li>
```

Basically new content gets added to the start of this list, and to the end of this list archive content gets added as the user scrolls.

Im using delegate on other parts of the page and it works but not this part.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the relevant HTML; what are the actual elements involved?

Comment: How can you have `#submit` in both static and dynamically loaded content? IDs are supposed to be unique on the page, you know

Comment: I've now added some of the HTML from the page.

Answer (score 1):

My first guess would be that this is caused because you're trying to add multiple `#submit` elements.  Element IDs are unique and should not be used more than once.  I'd suggest switching to a `submit` class and trying again with...

```
$('#fav').delegate(".submit", "click", function() {
```

You should also switch your usage of #favid.

Answer (score 0):

does the statically loaded #fav div wrap all #submits, or just one?  i assume the issue is that your delegating it to an object that isn't high enough on the dom.  try replacing #fav with body, or some wrapper element.

additionally, as commented above, you should not use ids more than once on a given page, so a class .submit would be preferable.

```
$('body').delegate(".submit", "click", function() {

    var favid = $("input#favid").val();
    var favsave = 'favid=' + favid;
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "fav.php",
      data: favsave,
      success: function() {
        $('#fav').fadeOut(100);
      }
    });
    return false;

});
```

you'll probably need to add some context to those jquery selectors as well.

Comment: @JacobM, edited to include that, though if you were really going to nitpick, we should also make sure that the input#favid is either unique or changed to a class as well.  also, i'm making the assumption that even the #fav element's id is not unique, so that should probably be a class as well

Answer (score 0):

Which part of the page is being dynamically generated?  If the element with ID of #fav is being dynamically generated then it won't work.  You'll need to delegate the event handler to an element that exists on the page at the time the event is bound.

More info, preferably the HTML markup in question? :)